# Java String.replace() - replaces more than just the substring I specify?

Tags: java, string, replace, startswith, ends-with

As per [this CodingBat problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p151940) I am trying to do the following:

> Given a string, if the first or last chars are 'x', return the string without those 'x' chars, and otherwise return the string unchanged.

My code:

```
public String withoutX(String str) {
    if (str.startsWith("x")) {
        str = str.replace(str.substring(0, 1), "");
    }
    if (str.endsWith("x")) {
        str = str.replace(str.substring(str.length()-1), "");
    }
    return str;
}
```

This code replaces ALL the `x` characters in the string, rather than just the first and last. Why does this happen, and what would be a good way to solve it?

Comment: The reason this happens is that `str.replace(str.substring(0,1), "");` reduces to `str.replace("x","");` which means "replace every 'x' with '' ". By the time `replace` is being executed, the first argument is just a string "x"; it doesn't have any information about where that string came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sdk for the `replace` method:

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing **all** occurrences of
>   oldChar in this string with newChar.

You can solve this without replace:

```
public String withoutX(String str) {   
    if (str == null) { 
        return null;
    }

    if (str.startsWith("x")) {
        str = str.substring(1);
    }
    if (str.endsWith("x")) {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fit when `str` is `x` - so it needs an extra `if` statement at the beginning to account for that

Comment: @alanbuchanan now it does ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("^x|x$", "");
```

The above code will replace the `x` which was at the start or at the end. If there is no `x` at the start or at the end, it would return the original string unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

You can use replaceFirst for first character or you can substring both side by 1 character

```
public static String withoutX(String str) {
        if (str.startsWith("x")) {
            str = str.replaceFirst("x", "");
        }
        if (str.endsWith("x")) {
            str = str.substring(0,str.length() - 1);
        }

        return str;
    }
```